# Cannot find symbol symbol method of() location interface java.util.list, unittests

Tags: java, list, spring-boot

I'm currently working on a spring boot application, where I'm now writing the unittests. But when I run the command 'mvn test', I get the following error:

[image]

This is the code

BoardServiceTest.java

```
@Test
public void testGetBoards() {
    Set<Lists> list =  new HashSet<Lists>();
    
    List<Board> expectedBoards = List.of(
        new Board(1, "Studie", list),
        new Board(2, "Todo Applicatie", list)
    );
    
    when(this.boardRepo.findAll()).thenReturn(expectedBoards);
    
    var receivedBoards = this.boardService.getBoards();
    assertEquals(expectedBoards, receivedBoards);
    verify(this.boardRepo, times(1)).findAll();
}
```

ListsServiceTest.java

```
@Test
public void testGetLists() throws Exception {   
    int boardId = 1;
    Set<Task> task = new HashSet<>();

    List<Lists> expectedLists = List.of(
        new Lists(1, "registered", new Board(), task),
        new Lists(2, "open", new Board(), task)
    );
    
    when(this.listRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(expectedLists);
    
    var receivedLists = this.listService.getLists(boardId);
    
    assertEquals(expectedLists, receivedLists);
    verify(this.listRepository, times(1)).findAll();
}
```

Comment: In the future please don't post screenshots of error messages, post the error message itself as text instead.

Comment: @JoachimSauer i didn't now that, but i couldn't copy the full error. That's the reason why i did a screenshot. But i will don't do it in the future

Answer (score 12):

`List.of` was added in [Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of--), you need to make sure that you use JDK 9+  to compile your sources and that appropriate java version is set in the maven `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Java8 to resolve this error :
List openApiEndpoints =
Arrays.asList("/api/auth/register", "/api/auth/token");